# Missing checkbox in Java security dialog

Tags: java, security, dialog

I have a signed jar with a manifest including permissions and codebase resulting in this dialog:[image]

I would though like this dialog to be shown instead: [image]

This dialog provides the user to always accept my certificate on my page.
But I just can not seem to figure out why I am not getting the checkboxed dialog.

Comment: Which version of JRE?

Comment: JRE 1.7.0_45 is used when showing the dialogs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer myself.

I added these three lines to my manifest file which brought back the checkbox:

```
Application-Name: Name
Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase: *
Caller-Allowable-Codebase: *
```